# ¿Cómo hacer infinito mi encabezado?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un trabajo que consiste en hacer un encabezado que diga: "bienvenido. Diseño web con: html css javascript". ya lo hice usando javascript pero necesito que mi encabezado se desarrolle de forma infinita.

ya usé la propiedad *infinite* para que mi encabezado sea constante pero no sirve.

Este es mi código:

```
<style>
        * {padding:0;margin:0;}
        .div{width: 100%;height: 100vh;color: green;border: 1px solid coral;box-sizing: border-box;}
        .div2{margin: auto; width: 70%;height: auto;color: green;border: 1px solid coral;box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;font-size: 1.8em;margin-top:30px;padding: 20px;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div">

        <div id="hijo" class="div2"></div>


        <script>
            function mifuncion(){
           /*las funciones dentro de mi funcion se van a cumplir con un retrazos de tiempo de dos segundos uno mayor 
            * que el otro*/
          setTimeout(primero, 2000);
          setTimeout(segundo, 4000);
          setTimeout(tercero, 6000);/*tengo en mi funcion anidada muchas */
          setTimeout(cuarto, 8000);/*funciones las cuales van a ser invocadas*/
          setTimeout(quinto, 10000);
          setTimeout(sexto, 12000);

        };
        function primero(){
                document.getElementById("hijo").innerHTML="bienvenidos";
            }
             function segundo(){
                document.getElementById("hijo").innerHTML="Diseo web con:";
            }
             function tercero(){
                document.getElementById("hijo").innerHTML="HTML";
            }
             function cuarto(){
                document.getElementById("hijo").innerHTML="CSS";
            }
             function quinto(){
                document.getElementById("hijo").innerHTML="JAVASCRIPT";
            }
            function sexto(){
                document.getElementById("hijo").innerHTML="Diseo web con:<br>html css javascript";
            }

            var myvar = document.getElementById("hijo");
            myvar.addEventListener("mouseover",mifuncion);
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: a que te refieres con "hacer infinito"?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes optimizarlo de la siguiente forma

```
var index = 0;
//Generas una array para los diferentes titulos, en orden
var titles = [
    "Bienvenido",
    "Diseño web"
];
//Aqui puedes correr la funcion inicial sin utilizar mouseover
mifuncion();

function mifuncion() {
    // Se ejecuta el primer cambio
    changeTitle();
    //setInterval hace lo mismo que setTimeout pero en ciclos
    setInterval(changeTitle, 2000);
}

function changeTitle () {
     //Se obtiene el texto de la lista
     var text = titles[index];
     //Se incrementa el índice para el array
     index++;
     if (index >= titles.length) {
         //Si el índice es mayor que la cantidad de titulos, se reinicia
         index = 0;
     }
     document.getElementById("hijo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Lo hice tal como esta allí pero no ejecuta el código.

Comment: Creo que tengo un atajo que no había pensado antes. si pongo el div hijo en un width del 100% y y el height vh significaria que el usuario permanecería haciendo mouseover a cada rato y el código se ejecutaría por doquier.

Comment: No, es mala práctica, comenta que errores te arroja la consola

Comment: Si copiaste mi código tal cual, tenia un error por un caracter, mandaba llamar a `mifunction` cuando en realidad era a `mifuncion`; prueba con mi nuevo cambio